# ramda documentation map missing commas

Tags: ramda.js

For the map method, why isn't it like the 2nd line instead of the 1st? It takes 2 parameters, a function, and something else, so why does it have 2 of the arrows?

```
Filterable f => (a → Boolean) → f a → f a

Filterable f => (a → Boolean) , f a → f a
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Briefly, you can replace a function of multiple arguments:

```
const f = (x, y) => x + y;

f(1, 2) // 3
```

With a series of functions of one argument:

```
const f = x => y => x + y;

f(1)(2) // 3
```

One advantage being that it’s easier to [partially apply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) a curried function:

```
const add1 = f(1);

add1(2) // 3
```

This is used extensively in Haskell, which seems to be a source of inspiration for ramda.js, and in turn the [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) on which Haskell is based.

Note that the function arrow type is right-associative, so these are equivalent:

```
Filterable f => (a → Boolean) →  f a → f a
Filterable f => (a → Boolean) → (f a → f a)
```

Seen this way, a function of this type converts a predicate on `a`s into a transformation on `f`s of `a`s.

There’s also a relation to simple algebra: in type theory, a tuple `(a, b)` corresponds to a *product* (a × b), and a function arrow `a → b` corresponds to exponentiation (b<sup>a</sup>). You can convert between `a → b → c` and `(a, b) → c` for the same reason you can convert between (c<sup>b</sup>)<sup>a</sup> and c<sup>b × a</sup>.

Comment: thanks for the explanation but I still don't see it even with the parentheses. The `Filterable f => (a → Boolean)` represents the function that map takes in, but where does it show the array parameter that it can take in?

Comment: @stackjlei: `Filterable f` is a constraint on the entire type `(a → Boolean) → f a → f a`. The array parameter would be the `f`. For example, if you pass in a function of type `Number → Boolean` as the first argument, then `a` = `Number`; and if you pass an array as the second parameter, then `f` = `Array`, so the whole type is specialised to `(Number → Boolean) → Array Number → Array Number`. This is all sort of handwaving of course, because JavaScript lacks types—they’re just using the Haskell-esque notation as a descriptive tool.